# Data response in console returned HTML code

Tags: php, reactjs

After deploying the build folder on my production instance I tried to login but it doesn't get the value of session so I tried to debug my code and use console.log but when I did, all it returned was the HTML code calling the main js created after running npm run build. It supposed to return the data from the database, but I got this instead.

```
data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset…s/main.c5c9f3bb.chunk.js"></script></body></html>"
```

Is this supposed to happen after deploying build of react project in production?

Comment: i think it's not your problem. check with backend api response.

Comment: I tried to access the url calling the php file that connects my react project to the database but the output is blank page.

Comment: check that api postman and if it's working in local then should work in production also.

Comment: It's working on my local instance. This issue occurred after I deployed the files from the build project of my react in production.

Comment: I tried the api postman, what I get was the html code

Comment: if you are getting same html response in postman it means your api having issue not from frontend side.